# Python ElasticSearch updating field on multiple documents without script compilation rate limit

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import UpdateByQuery
UpdateByQuery(index=index).using(es_client).query("match", id=<my_obj_id>)\
            .script(source=f"ctx._source.view_count=12345")
```

to update the `view_count` field on one of my ElasticSearch documents.

The problem is on production there are a lot of documents that need updating and I get

```
TransportError(500, 'general_script_exception', '[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.context.update.max_compilations_rate] setting')
```

I'm not sure if increasing the limit is a long-term solution. However I don't know how I'd do a bulk update over multiple documents at once to avoid so many calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) it allows to update multiple documents at once (see example there).

Generally, you should try to use "doc" updates instead of "script" whenever possible.